# best way to cache lookup tables in memory

Tags: c#, linq, caching

I have a few hundreds lookup tables that i would like to cache in memory.
I have dragged and dropped them onto Linq to sql entity mapper.I imagine there must be a better(Genric) way to read the data in memory than loading each individual table using "HttpContext.Current.Cache" object.
All the lookup tables start with "L_"  followed by the name of the type of the content.

Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Best

Comment: A high speed in memory cache like Redis might be a better approach.

Comment: Will this outperform Microsoft's own on disk caching? This feature has been available to asp.net for years now

Comment: I can't say, but I would expect hundreds of tables to put memory pressure on the web server which could offset the benefit. I can say that Redis is amazingly fast and made specifically for this kind of thing.

Comment: i do have 32 GB of memory om my server and the data needs for the application will never exceed 10 GB. So memory will not be an issue

Comment: Beside i will find it hard to convince management to invest in an other technology.

Comment: I'm not a tuning expert by any means, but I don't think caching works that way - meaning simple how much memory do I have and  how much do I need. [See this](http://www.monitis.com/blog/2012/07/16/improving-asp-net-performance-part-8-caching). But if you want an easy way to get all that data I would create a stored procedure instead of using LtoE that returns multiple results sets that can be iterated over with reader.nextresult, then add them to cache.

Comment: Caching is from my experience the number one mean to obtain massive performance gain. Sites like Facebooks and google would be unimaginable without the use of dedicated caching technologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106099/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-meelfan-bmfp).

Answer (score 0):

10 GB is too much of data to be cached.

Use .NET's (probably System.Cache namespace) own cache. You will be able to reuse your cache code if you ever write Web API for mobile apps etc.

ASP.NET cache uses WeakLinks and whenever memory is required, your occasionally used Cache Items will be removed.

Use Redis if you want distributed cache or need persistence with your cache.

Using Sql Server's own In memory tables with Stored Procedures would be better than using Entity Framework (but not Redis).

Write your service layer code like this (this code will be reusable with your Web APIs too)

```
private IList<TableName> GetAll()
{
    //find in cache and return  
    //load data if upper step doesn't find data in cache 
    // store data in cache for this specific lookup 
    // return data 
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: should memorycache be singleton or scoped?